# Fetching particular data of current user from Firestore [Swift]

Tags: swift

here you are a screenshot of a result and I would like to grab skills object of current user in firestore into the tableview. Any feedback regarding this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
func getSkills() {
    guard (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid) != nil else {
        return
    }
    self.db.collection("tutors").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let docId = document.documentID
                let addedSkills = document.get("skills") as! Array<Any>
            
        print(docId, addedSkills)
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and please do not paste code via image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems way too generic, I think you can get away with any `UITableView` tutorial (with networking) out there. However, there are some points you may be aware regardless.

The `addedSkills` in you example above seems scoped local to the callback. You may remove the `let` before `addedSkills`, so compiler can pick up the right reference. Also don't forget to call `tableView.reloadData` once you have populated the view with new data.

In addition, you may spare force unwrapping things to avoid crashing you app, something like below.

```swift
if let documents = querySnapshot?.documents
{
    for document in documents
    {
        if let addedSkills = document.get("skills") as? Array<Any>
        {
            // Log.
            let documentID = document.documentID
            print(documentID, addedSkills)

            // Update data.
            self.addedSkills = addedSkills

            // Update UI.
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to be more conscious about selecting the right document though, instead of iterating over each. Try setting a breakpoint to your `print` statement to see the entire (!) `documents` object.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, it seems to be because you are declaring another `addedSkills`   array within the completion block of your query. You should change it to this

```
func getSkills() {
guard (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid) != nil else {
    return
}
self.db.collection("tutors").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            let docId = document.documentID
            self.addedSkills = document.get("skills") as! Array<Any> // This is the change

    print(docId, addedSkills)
        }
}
```

}
}